# After the client received notice of the established CONNECT, it failed to send any data

Tags: https, fiddler

I'm using fiddler to debug android app, I can capture the HTTP request and Http response, but I can not capture the HTTPS request/response , I already install the fiddler root certificate.

The request is :

```
    #   Result  Protocol    Host    URL                        Body  Caching    Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
   119  200     HTTP     Tunnel to  api.find.nutspace.com:443   0
```

In the request inspector , I got that:
After the client received notice of the established CONNECT, it failed to send any data.

I got no response body data , the headers of the response is :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 11:49:35.178
Connection: close
```

Can anyone know why it failed to send any data?

Answer (score 2):

When this problem occurs, the typical explanation is that you failed to properly configure Android to trust Fiddler's root certificate. As a consequence, after the Connection is established, the Android application examines the certificate, notes that it is not trusted, and decides not to use the connection to send a secure request.

You haven't specified what application you're using, how you attempted to trust the certificate, and whether you can capture HTTPS traffic in the Android browser.